# Change behaviour of an animation - AN

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I'm starting to use animation nodes so I can easily make some cool animations at my work to show case some products.

I've been able to move a list of objects and arrange them the way I want, but I don't know how I can make another animation with that.

I've made some objects to gather by the world origin, now I want to move them away, leaving just one in the center of the screen.
 I'm able to do that separately, but I have no idea of how I can make it continuously.

[image: animate In]

[image: animation out]

[image: current nodetree]

Edit: @Omar:Thanks for your answer, I've been able to make the in and outwards animation, biggest issue that I have is that I'd need to remove one object from the list and move the rest of them. Of course I'm able to do that with keyframes, but would like to learn it using AN
I'd like to do something like that:

[image]

Comment: So you just want them to converge then diverge in the same animation continuously?

Comment: Yeah, and then I'd like to animate something else...

Comment: I just edited the answer, is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

First, create the initial animation using an approach like this:

[image: Initial Animation]

Next, we take the output time and delay it by some amount using a *Delay Node*. This time is then used as the time for an *Animate Vector* node, the start vector will be a zero vector (No offset) and the end vector will be the offset vector. A list is then filled with this vector to match the objects' count. Finally, we set a certain list element to zero, this element corresponds to the object that will not move. Then the list is added to the vectors:

[image: Second Animation]

Comment: Hello, Omar, how you doing?

Sorry about that long time to check your answer, got busy these days. I couldn't even replicate your results since my "Distribute Matrices" doesn't give me the option to output it to Vertices, only to Matrices. Am I missing something on it's configuration?

Comment: @eduklafke I am using a new build that have this option, in your case, you can just use the *Decompose Matrix* node to get the vectors for the matrices.